# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'color_code' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables `products` and `colors`.

I want to store multiple rows in multiple tables within my database. My controller is currently not storing multiple values, it is only saving one row in my products and item lists tables.

**How to save array in database?**

blade

```
<div class="row no-gutters mb-1">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="color_name" class="ml-1">نام رنگ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color_name" name="color_name[]" class="form-control w-auto d-inline">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="color_code" class="ml-1">کد رنگ:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code[]" class="form-control w-75 d-inline jscolor">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <a onclick="addColor()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
        <a onclick="deleteColor()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

ProductController.php

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $product = Product::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'latin' => $request->latin,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'discount' => $request->discount,
        'coupon' => $request->coupon,
        'order_product' => 0,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'keywords' => $request->keywords,
        'descriptions' => $request->descriptions,
    ]);
    $color = new Color;
    $color->product_id = $product->id;
    $color->color_code = $product->color_code;
    $color->color_name = $product->color_name;
    $color->save();
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

I want to save title, price, coupon and ....... in products table, and I want to save multiple color_name[] and color_code[] in colors table.

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'color_code' cannot be null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'latin' => $request->latin,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'discount' => $request->discount,
        'coupon' => $request->coupon,
        'order_product' => 0,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'keywords' => $request->keywords,
        'descriptions' => $request->descriptions,
    ]);
        
    $colorCodes = $request->color_code;
    $colorNames = $request->color_name;

    foreach ($colorCodes as $key => $color_code) {
        $color = new Color;
        $color->product_id = $product->id;
        $color->color_code = $color_code;
        $color->color_name = $colorNames[$key];
        $color->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the array you have to store in database use

```
foreach($color_code as $cc){
  //code here
}
```

then you should store in database or you should also use

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($color_code); i++) {
 // code here
}
```

and store in database it will help you.